# createWebPrintJob not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have this code in my activity which prints the webview as pdf, but after printing it always save pdf in size 0bytes, and unable to open that pdf.

```
private void createWebPrintJob() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
            PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = binding.webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
            String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test";
            printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                    new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Print is not supported below Android KITKAT Version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated, Thanks.

[This is android emulator image showing downloaded PDF Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6c6.png)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are calling

```
createWebPrintJob();
```

Method after your webview has called the load method and the data is loaded in the web view.